# Alguno de ustedes ha hecho en php lo siguientes dentro de un for mostrar varios mapas con google map indicando la ubicacion de un lugar?

Tags: php, javascript

```js
 <script async defer>
    
  function initMap() {
    var esta_latitud=$("#map").attr("latitud");
        var esta_longitud=$("#map").attr("longitud");
   
        var uluru = {lat: parseInt(esta_latitud), lng: parseInt(esta_longitud)};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="row">



           <?php
    
    $row = $controller->listar_foto_categoria_equipos_comida();
    foreach ($row as $k) {
    ?>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <img  style=" max-width: 100%; height: 400px; padding: 10px;" src="<?php echo "../../".$k['foto']; ?>" alt=""  />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="tarjeta">
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">Beneficio <i class="fa fa-handshake-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><?php echo $k['nombre']; ?></p><br>
       <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">Telefono <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><?php echo $k['esta_telefono']; ?></p><br>
      <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">Direccion<i class="fa fa-street-view" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><?php echo $k['esta_direccion']; ?></p><br>
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">Vigencia hasta:<i class="fa fa-hourglass-half" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><?php echo $controller->fechaCastellano($k['caducidad']); ?></p>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 ">
        <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; position: absolute;left: 50%; top: -30px;"><label></label><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></p>
        <div class="m" id="map" latitud="<?php echo $k['esta_latitud'];?>" longitud="<?php echo $k['esta_longitud'];?>"  ></div>
        </div>

  <?php
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: si la respuesta sea si o no... cual sería la siguiente pregunta?

Comment: pues estoy capturando la latitud y longitud desde php y enviandola a javascript por medio de attr asi  <div class="m" id="map" latitud="<?php echo $k['esta_latitud'];?>" longitud="<?php echo $k['esta_longitud'];?>"  ></div></div> pero resulta y pasa que en la Base de Datos hay tres registros o lugares y al enviarle los dos parametros solo me muestra un mapa y deberia mostrar tres si se pudiera, anteriormente lo hacia con <iframe> que generaba google pero asi era mas dificil

Answer (score 0):

Recorrería todos los elementos `map` una vez cargadas y recoger los datos para iniciarlo con google maps...

```js
$(function() {
   
    $('.map').each(function(i){
       
        var _this    = $(this);
        var latitud  = _this.attr('latitud');
        var longitud = _this.attr('longitud');
        
        console.log( 'Elemento #' + (i+1), latitud );
        console.log( 'Elemento #' + (i+1), longitud );        
        
        /*        
        Y con estos datos puedes iniciar el mapa de google
        
        var uluru = {lat: parseInt(latitud), lng: parseInt(longitud)};
        var map = new google.maps.Map( _this, { zoom: 4, center: uluru });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });        
        */
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ejemplo resultado -->
<div class="map" latitud="lat123" longitud="lng456"></div>
<div class="map" latitud="lat123" longitud="lng456"></div>
<div class="map" latitud="lat123" longitud="lng456"></div>
```

Además trabajaría con los atributos `data-*` ya que no son *válidas*

Ejemplo:

```
<div class="map" data-latitud="lat123" data-longitud="lng456"></div>
```

y en tu `jQuery` lo recoges te esta forma:

```
var latitud  = _this.data('latitud');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu lógica es básicamente correcta (no bonita, pero correcta). Sin embargo cada ID en el DOM debe ser único, o de lo contrario sólo tomará en cuenta el primer elemento con ese ID. Lo que debieras hacer es asignar IDs distintos:

```
<?php
 foreach ($row as $index => $k) {
?>

<div class="m" id="map_<?php echo $index;?>" latitud="<?php echo $k['esta_latitud'];?>" longitud="<?php echo $k['esta_longitud'];?>"  ></div>


<?php
 }
?>
```

Con lo cual tendrías ids distintos (map_0, map_1, map_2).

Sin embargo puede que ni siquiera necesites darles id a los mapas. La solución que plantea aldanux puede completarse haciendo:

```
$(function() {

    $('.map').each(function(i){

        var _this    = $(this);
        var latitud  = _this.attr('latitud');
        var longitud = _this.attr('longitud');

        var uluru = {lat: parseInt(latitud), lng: parseInt(longitud)};
        var map = new google.maps.Map( _this[0], { zoom: 4, center: uluru });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });        

    });
});
```

Ojo, que el constructor de google maps usaría `_this[0]` que es un HTMLElement. `_this` vendría siendo un selector de jQuery.